# yum: enable a disabled repository

Tags: yum, redhat-enterprise-linux, repository

I've found out I can use `yum --enablerepo=` to [temporarily enable](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Software_Management_Guide/ch05s10.html) a disabled Yum repository, but I want to *permanently* enable a repository.

Is there a preferred Yum command to enable a disabled repository, or should I edit the `.repo` file under `/etc/yum.repos.d`?

Using RHEL 5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: the configuration files must be edited with a text editor. Yum does not have commands or options to edit the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PackageKit on top of yum, you can do it with `pkcon`:

```
% pkcon repo-disable myrepo
Enabling repository           [=========================]         
Waiting in queue              [=========================]         
Waiting for authentication    [=========================]         
Waiting in queue              [=========================]         
Starting                      [=========================]         
Getting information           [=========================]         
% pkcon repo-enable myrepo
Enabling repository           [=========================]         
Waiting in queue              [=========================]         
Waiting for authentication    [=========================]         
Waiting in queue              [=========================]         
Starting                      [=========================]         
Getting information           [=========================]         
Downloading repository information[=========================]
```

Note that, as the output indicates, running the command as a regular user typically means you'll be prompted for authentication before it'll complete.

Comment: (Yes, it really does start the repo-disable output with "Enabling repository". ...I have no idea.)