# Is it possible to enable / disable yum repository using dnf?

Tags: fedora, redhat-enterprise-linux, repository

How to enable/disable yum repo (i.e. set `enabled=0/1` in `/etc/yum.repo.d/*.repo` files) using dnf?

According to question [*yum: enable a disabled repository*](https://superuser.com/questions/570285/yum-enable-a-disabled-repository) yum can't do that.

Used system: Fedora 21

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Enable a repository:

```
dnf config-manager --set-enabled <repo>
```

Disable a repository:

```
dnf config-manager --set-disabled <repo>
```

Show help:

```
dnf config-manager --help-cmd
```

The first two should be run with superuser rights.

DNF config-manager Plugin [documentation](http://dnf-plugins-core.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config_manager.html).

Comment: It works since Fedora 22.

Answer (score 2):

on 21 yum is still the default package tool.  so you would  either:
1) yum-config-manager --save  --disablerepo=foo (replace foo with  reponame.repo)

2) sudo vi (or any other comfy editor) /etc/yum.repos.d/foo.repo  and  edit the enabled=0/1  line and save  (while a # yum clean all ; #yum update is not generally required it is generally  seen as a good practice)

dnf  can do the exact same  but as mentioned above  dnf is not default till 22 ( still in RC state thru may 5 2015)  and has some known issues with fc21  consider  looking at  yum-dnf-$arch  in the interim as well as a possible workaround / crutch...